# sitecore RSS caching

Tags: c#, caching, rss, sitecore

I have been working on implementing a custom RSS feed in sitecore 6.4. My custom behaviour is very limited, all i effectively wanted to is add a link for author (our author field is a reference field so we cannot use the built in author attribution).

I overrode `RenderItem()` on the `PublicFeed` class so that i could make use of my own implementation of the `FeedRenderer` class (where the author logic is housed). my approach follows this **[pattern outlined by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/09/Customize-URLs-in-Public-RSS-Feeds-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)** for adding your own rendering behaviour:

```
public class MyPUblicFeed: PublicFeed
{

    protected override SyndicationItem RenderItem(Item item)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
        Control rendererControl = FeedUtil.GetFeedRendering(item);

        if (rendererControl == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        using (new ContextItemSwitcher(item))
        {
            var myRenderer= rendererControl as MyFeedRenderer;
            if (myRenderer!= null)
            {
                myRenderer.Database = SitecoreHelper.CurrentDatabase.Name;
                return myRenderer.RenderItem();
            }

            var renderer = rendererControl as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer;
            if (renderer != null)
            {
                renderer.Database = SitecoreHelper.CurrentDatabase.Name;
                return renderer.RenderItem();
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("FeedRenderer rendering must be of Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer type");
    }

}
```

And now for my rendering class:

```
public class MyFeedRenderer: Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer
{

    public override SyndicationItem RenderItem()
    {
        Item item = base.GetItem();
        var syndicationItem = base.RenderItem();

        //unfortunately we have to parse params again :(
        FeedRenderingParameters feedRenderingParameter = FeedRenderingParameters.Parse(base.Parameters);

        AddAuthor(syndicationItem, item, feedRenderingParameter);

        return syndicationItem;
    }


    private static void AddAuthor(SyndicationItem syndicationItem, Item item, FeedRenderingParameters feedRenderingParameter)
    {
        //clear out authors added by base class
        syndicationItem.Authors.Clear();

        //logic for adding author here
    }
}
```

this all works great, outputting exactly what i want, but the caching element doesn't appear to be working. I have set the `cacheable` flag on the actual item itself with a timespan of `01:00:00`. This didn't appear to work - if i put a breakpoint in either of the above classes it is hit everytime the feed is requested.

so then i tried to enable caching at a control level, turning caching on with `VaryByData` for the `MyFeedRenderer` rendering. alas this isn't working either, the breakpoint is hit every time.

Can anyone offer any advice on this matter? the documentation simply recommends turning it on on the actual feed item, not at the Rendering level, but neither seem to be working for me. Interestingly HTML caching is working elsewhere - is RSS also put into the HTML cache?

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

-Ensure the Cacheable checkbox in the feed definition item is checked.

-Ensure that you have published the feed definition item.

-If you do not populate the Cache Duration field in the feed definition item, it should default to one day.

-Feeds appear to cache in Sitecore.Syndication.FeedManager.Cache rather than the site output cache. Inspect that cache object in the Visual Studio debugger after calling your feed, and then again after calling that feed a second time, to try to see if any records appear, and if multiple cache keys appear for the same feed. Investigate the Render() method; if PublicFeed.IsCacheable() returns false (depending on the Cacheable field in the feed definition item), PublicFeed.Render() does not cache.

-Ensure nothing else clears caches between your requests for the feed.

SDN forum thread: http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=40591

Comment: thanks for adding your input here John - good work joining SO also :) Have you ever considered setting up a stack exchange specifically for sitecore?